# xml parsing getting inner value

Tags: powershell, xml-parsing

I am trying to understand how nodes work in order to get their values.
The sample XMl code is

```
<MediaContainer size="1">
    <Video addedAt="1463113546"> 
        <User id="365343" thumb="something" title="UserA"/>
    </Video>
</MediaContainer>
```

I know below will get the User ID using powershell, however trying to also get the title value which contains the username.

```
 $xml.MediaContainer.Video.User.id
```

When looping through not every line that has a User id will have a thumb value. In other words it can also say

```
 <User id="343" title="UserB"/>
```

Comment: Did you even try? :S Also, remember to mark the chosen answer as correct in your questions so the question will get closed and future readers will know that it worked.

Comment: of course I do, I had user.id.title that's why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First ,

```
[System.Xml.XmlDocument]$xml = new-object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$xml.load(<file_path>)
```

Then,

Get User ID : `$xml.MediaContainer.Video.User.id`

Get title : `$xml.MediaContainer.Video.User.title`